# MySQL: How to query multiple tables and apply a LIMIT to only one?

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have one table with *items* and another table with *subitems*. I would like to return *all* of the subitems associated with a limited number of items. In essence I would like to join these two queries:

```
SELECT * FROM subitem

SELECT * FROM item LIMIT 10
```

where `subitem.item = item.id`:

I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM subitem INNER JOIN item ON subitem.item = item.id LIMIT 10
```

However, this query only returns 10 subitems (as you would expect). I would like to retrieve *all* the subitems while limiting only the number of *items* to 10. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you mind an indeterminate selection, or are you applying some ordering before the `LIMIT`?

Comment: I will need to apply some ordering to both the items and the subitems (I left that out of the example to keep things simple)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will get you 10 items.  However, you should add a WHERE clause and ORDER BY clause to get the items you are looking for.

```
SELECT * FROM subitem INNER JOIN 
              (SELECT * FROM items LIMIT 10) AS I
              ON subitem.item = I.id
```

Comment: this way is better than `WHERE IN (SELECT...)` because it can use the index on `subitem.item`

Answer (score 3):

Try with following query:

```
select * from item,subitem where id = item and 
  id in (select id from item limit 10)
```

If there is problem with `IN` in `LIMIT`, try with following query:

```
select * from (select id from item limit 10) as i1, subitem where id =item ;
```

Comment: I tried this and got the following error: Error Code: 1235. This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'. I checked the version number of MySQL and its 5.5.24.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. However, I ended up using multiple JOIN statements, which allowed me to compartmentalize my rather complex query and make it easier to read. As far as I could tell, though, both methods performed equally as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

SELECT * FROM subitem WHERE item IN (SELECT id FROM item LIMIT 10);

Answer (score -1):

how to use limit in this query

```
select tbl_thread.id,user_id,name,tbl_User.alert_flag,thread_name,thread_status,(select CAST(count(*) as UNSIGNED) from tbl_message where thread_id=tbl_thread.id AND read_status='0' and msg_from='EU' ) as unread,thread_timestamp,(select CAST(max(id) as UNSIGNED) from tbl_message where thread_id=tbl_thread.id) as max_id from tbl_thread,tbl_User where tbl_User.UserID=user_id ;
```